# Apprpriate Timer object to run audio in WPF

Tags: wpf, timer

I have large WPF application which also uses MEF.
I want to trigger an Audio alert on certain condition and repeat it for the times specified by user. audio file can be .wav or .mp3.

I am making use of SoundPlayer to play the audio. 
I am not sure which timer to use for repeat intervals.

I dont want to block UI thread when audio is playing and also want it to be threadsafe.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider using Event Aggregation, which is an implementation of publisher subscriber pattern. Whenever your application encounters a condition where it wants to play audio, it would publish its intensions via the event aggregator.

There would be a listener who listens for these events and would play the correct audio based on the type of the event. If there are multiple requests, the listener may play them in parallel or in a sequence. You can implement the desired threading model within the listener and standard thread-sleep

This way, you get to keep all you audio configuration and logic tucked behind a single module. All the other modules will just ‘tell’ this module what they want to play (and optionally for how long)

On the other hand, unless your application is large enough the above approach would be an overkill

A good write-up on event aggregation 
http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2009/02/23/event-aggregation-with-mef-with-and-without-eventaggregator/